# Best strategy to keep aspect ratio consistent for all videos having any resolution

Tags: ffmpeg, transcoding, aspect

I am using the following ffmpeg command to create multiple resolutions for the same video content.

```
ffmpeg -i ${f} -c:v libx264 -keyint_min 150 \
-g 150 -profile:v main -f h264 -dash 1 \
-an -vf scale=640:360 -b:v 750k ${streamsdirectory}/${filename}_640x360_750k.mp4 \
-an -vf scale=1280:720 -b:v 2000k ${streamsdirectory}/${filename}_1280x720_2000k.mp4 \
-an -vf scale=1920:1080 -b:v 4000k ${streamsdirectory}/${filename}_1920x1080_4000k.mp4
```

What is the best strategy to keep respect for the aspect ratio for any video content ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the output resolution to be 1280x720 and the video keeps its original ratio aspect as well:

```
ffmpeg  -v error -stats -i input -vf
"scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=1,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2"
output
```

Answer (score 1):

To keep aspect ratio change:

```
-vf scale=640:360
-vf scale=1280:720
-vf scale=1920:1080
```

to:

```
-vf scale=-2:360
-vf scale=-2:720
-vf scale=-2:1080
```

See [scale filter documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale) for more info.

Comment: How can I support both horizontal and vertical videos at the same time, say 1920x1080 and 1080x1920 ?

Comment: @UtkuBulkan See [Resizing videos to fit into specific size](https://superuser.com/a/1136305/110524).